# How to rename specific part of column names in R?

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I have some column names as follows `jan_20_5`, `feb_20_7`, `mar_20_3`, `apr_20_9`, etc.

I have 12 such columns and would like to eliminate everything after the second "_" and append something common by groups of three so that it outputs something like the following: `jan_20_winter`, `feb_20_winter`, `mar_20_winter`, `apr_20_spring`, `may_20_spring`, `jun_20_spring`, `jul_20_summer` etc.

How can I go about this in an efficient manner in R?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are `_5`, `_7`, `_3`, and `_9` the day-of-month? Do you have a definitive way to differentiate seasons? (They tend to vary based on region and year.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `stringr`, some regex finding the last digit in the string, and replace it with a vector of the seasons?

```
library(stringr)

# Fake data
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 12, nrow = 0))
colnames(df) <- paste(month.abb, 20:31, 4:15, sep = "_")

# Replacement
names(df) <- str_replace(names(df),
                         "\\d+$",
                         rep(c("winter", "spring", "summer", "autumn"), each = 3))

df
```

Output:

```r
 [1] Jan_20_winter Feb_21_winter Mar_22_winter Apr_23_spring May_24_spring Jun_25_spring Jul_26_summer
 [8] Aug_27_summer Sep_28_summer Oct_29_autumn Nov_30_autumn Dec_31_autumn
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the formatting, this may help you:

```r
# example colnames
cn <- c("jan_20_5", "feb_20_7", "mar_20_3", "apr_20_9", "may_20_18", "jun_20_8", "jul_20_4", "aug_20_7", "sep_20_5", "oct_20_4")


labl <- setNames(
 gl(4,3, labels = c("winter", "spring", "summer", "fall")),
 tolower(month.abb)
)

paste0(gsub("(.*_)(.*)", "\\1", cn), labl[gsub("_.*", "", cn)])
#>  [1] "jan_20_winter" "feb_20_winter" "mar_20_winter" "apr_20_spring"
#>  [5] "may_20_spring" "jun_20_spring" "jul_20_summer" "aug_20_summer"
#>  [9] "sep_20_summer" "oct_20_fall"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can make a simple mapping of `tolower(month.abb)` to season (in this example below I've mapped months 1:3, 4:6, 7:9, and 10:12 to winter, spring, summer, fall, but you may adjust this), and then replace the column names as below:

```
season=setNames(rep(c("winter","spring", "summer", "fall"),each=3),tolower(month.abb))

names(data) = sapply(str_remove(names(data),"_[0-9]{1,2}$"), \(k) {
  paste0(k,"_",season[[substr(k,1,3)]])
})
```